# Update DIV Classes with AJAX Json Array Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax Json Array result made of Divs in DOM. I want to update the existing DOM data with the new Ajax Json Result.   The DOM data and the Ajax data both have a id number that can  be used to match.  I used to have the form within the div, so it was easy to update because all I had to do was use $(this) or  $(this)closest.   Now I have moved the Ajax Get form  to outside the Div $(this) or  $(this)closest does not work.

I need also a method to relate the data and then apply the data based on the id or whatever you can recomend. Thank you.  Below is where I have got to so far.  The Ajax result new data below it shows the person with id:2 surname as Heals.   In the DOM div further below is Bond.  In a nutshell update each record with its update data.

```
<form  class="updateform"  action="" method="">    
<input type="hidden" class ="customers"  name="" value="<?php echo $mycustomers; ?>">
<a class="update-button"></a>
</form>
```

```
var Ajaxresultdata = [
 {id:1,name:"Mike",surname:"Rynes"},
 {id:2,name:"James",surname:"Heals"},
 {id:3,name:"Helen",surname:"Wright"}
 ];
```

Div rows are json Array result

```
<div class="mycustomers">
<div id="1">
    <div class="name">Mike </div>
    <div class="surname">Rynes</div>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <div class="name">James</div>
    <div class="surname">Bond</div>
</div>
<div id="3">
    <div class="name">Helen</div>
    <div class="surname">Wright</div> 
</div>
```

```
<script>
    var Ajaxresultdata = [
       { id: 1, name: "Mike", surname: "Rynes" },
       { id: 2, name: "James", surname: "Heals" },
       { id: 3, name: "Helen", surname: "Wright" }
   ];

   $.each(ajaxresultdata, function(i, person ) {
    
       if (document.getElementById(String(i)) {
           $("#" + String(i)).find('.surname').html(person.surname);
       }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: IDs can't be a number. So instead of using an id just use data attributes like `data-id="4"` and `document.querySelector("[data-id='4']");`

Comment: Thanks imvain2, may I ask : so I dont need if statements etc.  I just  oneline document selector?   or have you just advised me on  just one part of the problem. tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
   $.each(Ajaxresultdata, function( i, person ) {
     $("#"+person.id).html(person.surname);
   });
```

[check on codepen](https://codepen.io/neiroc/pen/RwoVojd)

Comment: FANTASTIC!!  I will get some sleep tonight :-).     10/10 for  for taking the time to display it in codepen, it really helps novices like me.  Thank you Neiroc!

Comment: I had to modify it abit to work for my setting, I  had to add the .find and class name as below.   $("#"+person.personid).find('.surname').html(person.surname).   Fantastic solution I modified it  for my delete and targeting other things.  Thanks Neiroc